# Run time error when Decimal() is not used

Tags: python, decimal

I am trying to solve this [question](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000434944/0000000000434d9a). My solution (as written) gives Runtime error

```
    import math
    from decimal import Decimal

    for i in range(int(input())):
        v,r=map(int,input().split())
        x=9.8

        ans=math.degrees(math.asin(r*x/(v*v))/2)
        format_float = "{:.7f}".format(ans)
        print("Case #"+str(i+1)+":",format_float)
```

but when I use `x = Decimal(9.8)` instead - it is accepted.

What is happening here? Also when or when not to use Decimal.

Time limit: 60 seconds.
Memory limit: 1 GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 4500 ,
1 ≤ V ≤ 300 ,
1 ≤ D ≤ 10000 ,
It is guaranteed that each test case will be solvable.

Comment: If you have an accepted answer, why do you need to speed it up?

Comment: Just an observation. `x` is the same for all test cases - no need to assign it each time.

Comment: still I am surprised that it is TLE in the given constraints

Comment: @PM77-1 it still doesn't make much difference

Comment: @KellyBundy yes I am getting RE runtime error , its same as TLE right?. Is this getting accepted?.

Comment: oh I see so why it's getting this error? should I always use decimal?

Comment: No, better understand why there is an error, don't rely on decimal somehow miraculously getting it right. There are only three million possible cases, you can try them all and see where float and decimal differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just solve all three million allowed cases with both `Decimal` and `float` and show where and how they differ:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def f(v, r):
    try:
        x=9.8
        ans=math.degrees(math.asin(r*x/(v*v))/2)
        format_float = "{:.7f}".format(ans)
        return format_float
    except:
        return 'error'
        
def d(v, r):
    try:
        x=Decimal(9.8)
        ans=math.degrees(math.asin(r*x/(v*v))/2)
        format_float = "{:.7f}".format(ans)
        return format_float
    except:
        return 'error'
        
for v in range(1, 301):
    for r in range(1, 10001):
        expect = d(v, r)
        result = f(v, r)
        if result != expect:
            print(f'{v=}  {r=}  Decimal:{expect}  float:{result}')
```

Output:

```
v=21  r=45  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=42  r=180  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=63  r=405  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=84  r=720  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=119  r=1445  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=126  r=1620  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=161  r=2645  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=168  r=2880  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=175  r=3125  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=231  r=5445  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=238  r=5780  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=245  r=6125  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
v=252  r=6480  Decimal:45.0000000  float:error
```

Let's look at the smallest one `v=21  r=45` more closely:

```
x = 9.8
v = 21
r = 45
print(r*x/(v*v))
```

Output:

```
1.0000000000000002
```

So, due to `float` imprecision, you happen to produce a number larger than 1, which `asin` then crashes on.

One way to avoid that in this case is to stay in integerland until the final division:

```
r*98/(10*v*v)
```

Using this, you get the same results as with `Decimal` in all allowed cases.